# Can anyone recommend some recent journal articles on the limitations of Quantum Computing

Tags: resource-recommendations, quantum-computer

More specifically, I would like some reading material on what the issue is with quantum computers, why can we not yet create them? Are there any journal articles that comprehensively list the reasons why we are struggling to create quantum computers? I would prefer for the research articles to be recent i.e. post 2013.

Comment: The issues are the same as with fusion reactors for energy production and interstellar spaceships... we don't have the required technology, yet. Would you have asked the question in 1955 why they can't put 256GByte of flash memory on a single chip and which journals have published the papers with the reasons? Would you have expected to get a good answer... rather than a blank stare?

Comment: But what limitations with the materials, I'm asking for specifics and references here. Why do we struggle with the material synthesis, what properties do these materials have as opposed to those in abundance in nature?

Comment: It's 1900 and somebody asks what the limitations to human flight are... what would have been your answer? Would you have told them that less than 70 years later two men would walk on the surface of the Moon? Really?  What do we struggle with? Mostly with paper that has the faces of US presidents on it. Rapid technological progress is usually linked to war or worse. What's your hurry here? Does it really matter whether you will have a quantum computer ten years from now or fifteen? I bet with you that you aren't even using your supercomputer.

Comment: If it was 1900 I would refer people to the works of Boyle as he speculates that flight of a body heavier than air is impossible and to previous works speculating that speed may be the key to achieving flight as air can be thought of like a liquid and  a bird flapping in the air akin to a duck treading water.

Comment: We know what some of the issues are with quantum computers. I understand that the issues right now are mainly material related. I'm looking for articles discussing what these issues are. You seem to be mistaken and think that I am asking for the answer to a question that we do not yet know the answer for; clearly I realise that if we knew how to make quantum computers we would have made them. What I'm actually looking for is journal articles discussing why current attempts at quantum computation have failed. This is something we do know.

Comment: To clarify, I know that no one knows the solution to said issues, I'm asking what said issues are. In your flight context the answer would be that we do not yet have the capability to make a heavy object move fast enough that "air will act like water".

Comment: The point is that physics can't predict the technological timelines of the future. If you had a dime for every false prediction of something being possible/impossible or the timelines, you could retire right now. Nothing known natural stands between us and quantum computing. I have a hypothetical idea why quantum computing may be a dead end, after all, but I am not a theoretician and I might as well be wrong. The issue has nothing to do with materials but is enshrined in the structure of quantum mechanics. Whether I am right or not will be decided by experiments, not by theory.

Comment: Every failure in science is actually a win because we learn the cause of the failure. In nature things don't just fail. They fail with hints of how one can gather the evidence of why they failed. Having said that, I stand by my comment that the only real problem is money. There is next to zero commercial interest in quantum computing, which is not a panacea to everyday computing problems. Quantum computing, even theoretically, at current is restricted to some rather esoteric problems that, in practice, are completely irrelevant. Nobody needs a quantum OS or a quantum multimedia player.

Comment: [Papers by the Martinis Group](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/publications.shtml) might mention what they're working on. Their editorial [Qubit metrology for building a fault-tolerant quantum
computer](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~martinisgroup/papers/Martinis2015.pdf) might have high-level context. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, high level context is not a problem. I just need some current papers on experimental failures of superconductors and theories that speculate why such failure occurred for my research paper.

Comment: Curious One I know we learn from failures in science which was why I was asking for journal articles pertaining to recent failures in attempts at Quantum Computers. Respectfuly I disagree that the problem is money, many commercial eneterprises have invested heavily in quantum computing, such as IBM. Any computer manufacturer that wishes to be in the market long term must research the subject. Not only are quantum computers exponentially faster than any conventional computer of the same number of bits, but also Moore's law will not continue to apply for as long as another decade

Comment: The miniturisation of computers has meant that quantum effects witihin them are literally an emerging issue. Soon Moore's law will be halted by the fact that it will be impossible to minituarise any further with current materials. Once the first quantum computer is availabe on the market, it will completely change computing. A qunatum computer could easily break any encryption not created by a quantum computer. This is why the US government has recently urged commercial scientists too slow down when it comes to QCs as their own researchers have not yet caught up.

Comment: I would like to say that nobody can be sure if the QC will finally be achieved. Since there are arguments that natural laws might not allow a general QC. For example, general adiabatic QC may not be achieved since the energy gap between 2 Hamiltonian may be exponentially small such that the adiabatic evolution takes an exponential time.  At least Aronson thought about this.